# Making URLs look better

Tags: url, nginx

I'm new to using Nginx, so currently I have this in my default file.

```
 location / {
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }

    location /templates/ {
              autoindex on;
              root /home/user/go/src/app/;
            }
```

So my URLs looks something like the link below depending on which page I'm on:

```
http://localhost:80/templates/index.html
```

How can I make Nginx reformat my URL to look something like:

```
http://localhost:80/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add location block like this

```
location / {
          # ...
          root /home/user/go/src/app/;
}
```

More information about locations [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Comment: I have a location block like that already, but the code that I presented above points to the directory where my HTML files are located.

Comment: You can replace that location block If it not already used by your web application